# Black screen on Anton's OpenGL Hello Triangle Tutorial

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL and started studying using [Anton's OpenGL](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/) tutorials.
I finished the "Hello Triangle" tutorial and compiled it without errors with the following g++ command:

```
g++ -o hello_triangle main.c -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -lm
```

However, the system window shows only a black screen, both in my code and in the code from the [book repository](https://github.com/capnramses/antons_opengl_tutorials_book).

The output from glGetString(GL_RENDERER) and glGetString(GL_VERSION) is the following:

```
Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile  
OpenGL version supported 3.0 Mesa 11.0.6
```

What might be the reason of this black screen?

If you want to check the code just look at the '00_hello_triangle' code.

Comment: checkout vertex & fragment shader, you will find the code use `#version 410` which is not supported by your GL. try replacing it with `#version 130`

Answer (score 0):

As @gnimuc-key suggested, when I changed the version in the shaders code, both vertex and fragment shader, it worked:

```
const char* vertex_shader =
    "#version 130\n"
    "in vec3 vp;"
    "void main () {"
    " gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 1.0);"
    "}"; 

const char* fragment_shader =
    "#version 130\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;"
    "void main () {"
    " frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);"
    "}";
```

I changed "#version 150" to "#version 130" and worked properly